# Is MongoDB supported by SonarQube?

Tags: mongodb, sonarqube

Can't see anywhere whether MongoDB is supported by SonarQube. If anyone could help that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB is not supported. Check this - http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements